# Object doesn't exist but IsObject returns true

Tags: qtp

I have a webTable where the first row is a sample row. 
Actual data are available from second row and they are editable and deletable with an inclusion of buttons Edit and Delete in column 3, 4 resp.

Test case is to check that sample data shouldn't be editable or deletable. Edit and Delete button is not available in the first row

I have the following script

```
Set Edit_Obj = Browser("B").Page("P").Frame("F").WebTable("WT").ChildItem(1, 3, "WebButton", 1)
Set Delete_Obj = Browser("B").Page("P").Frame("F").WebTable("WT").ChildItem(1, 4, "WebButton", 1)
```

`isObject(Edit_Obj)` returns `True` though when I try to perform a click operation on the object it throws an error that "Object is required"

Why does the `IsObject` function returns `True` when there is no object?
Any other way to work around this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChildItems` returns `Nothing` if no object matches the criteria and in VBScript `Nothing` is considered to be an object.

In order to see if `Edit_obj` is OK you should use

```
If Edit_Obj Is Nothing Then
```

You can also use `ChildItemCount` in order to know in advance if the object exists.

**Note:** The index parameter for `ChildItem` is zero based, not one based so in your code you're actually asking for the *second* button in the table cell, are you sure this is what you mean? I think it's more likely that you meant to write:

```
Set Edit_Obj = Browser("B").Page("P").Frame("F").WebTable("WT").ChildItem(1, 3, "WebButton", 0)
```

Comment: Yes I had intentionally put the index as '1' as the buttons in the other rows were being recognized at Index: 1. Thanks Motti for the explanation. I will check to see if this works